# Sum across columns if date is not missing and if year of date is after a certain number

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable called `bankruptcy_c`, which will equal to the number of times the year of `bankruptcy1, bankruptcy2, ..., bankruptcy10` is between 2007 and 2019, inclusive. At first, I created a variable that counted the number of times the columns had a date using the following code:

```
vars <- df %>%
  mutate(bankruptcy_c = rowSums(!is.na(across(contains("bankruptcy")))))
```

However, now I'm looking to only count each instance if the year is between 2007 and 2019. Here is some sample data:

```
structure(list(rowid = c(16L, 28L, 29L, 37L, 80778L), bankruptcy1 = structure(c(9282, 
11438, NA, 8664, 14048), class = "Date"), bankruptcy2 = structure(c(12892, 
NA, NA, 14809, 15012), class = "Date"), bankruptcy3 = structure(c(14713, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), bankruptcy4 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), bankruptcy5 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), bankruptcy6 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), bankruptcy7 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), bankruptcy8 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), bankruptcy9 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), bankruptcy10 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Using the sample data above, `bankruptcy_c` would equal to `1` for `rowid = 16`, `0` for `rowid = 28` (because the dates are out of range), `0` for `rowid = 29` (since all of the 10 instances are missing), `1` for `rowid = 37`, and `2` for `rowid = 80778`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure rowid 37 has none? `bankruptcy2` shows one in 2010.

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant 1! I'm making an edit to my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to reshape the data longer, filter, and count.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowid) %>%
  filter(year(as.Date(value)) %in% 2007:2019) %>%
  count(rowid) %>%
  complete(rowid = df$rowid, fill = list(n=0)) # EDIT to list all rowids


# alternate filter syntax if you care about specific dates:
filter(value >= as.Date("2007-01-01"), value < as.Date("2020-01-01")) %>%
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  rowid     n
  <int> <dbl>
1    16     1
2    28     0
3    29     0
4    37     1
5 80778     2
```

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry, I should have included a more detailed example. I do have some observations where the all of the instances of `bankruptcy1` to `bankruptcy10` are NA's or the years are out of the date range. I still want the newly created variable `bankruptcy_c`  to equal to `0` for those cases. Let me make an edit.

Comment: edited to add all rowids, even if no valid counts.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!